# The centralizer of an involution in a permutation group where $|\mbox{fix}(g)| \le 2$ for $g \ne 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite permutation group which acts transitive and nonregular on $\Omega$ in such a way that each nontrivial element fixes at most two points.

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ be distinct and such that $U := G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta} \ne 1$. Suppose that $|G_{\alpha}|$ is odd and that $|\Omega|$ is even. Suppose further that $G$ has no subgroup of index at most $2$ that is Frobenius group. Then there exists an involution $x \in N_G(U) \setminus U$ that interchanges $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and such that one of the following is true:

(1) $U$ is abelian. Moreover if $G$ is simple, then all involutions in $G$ are conjugate.

(2) $Z(C_G(x)) = \langle x \rangle$ and $C_G(x) / \langle x \rangle$ is a Frobenius group.

> Proof: [ I skip the part showing that $|N_G(U) : U| = 2$ and there exists an involution $x \in N_G(U) \setminus U$ ].
>
> If $C_U(x) \ne 1$, then we define $C := C_G(x)$ and we consider the action of $C$ on $\alpha^C$. If $|\alpha^C| \le 2$, then $C = \langle x \rangle \times U$ and thus the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Then $G$ has a normal $2$-complement $G_1$. But now $G_1$ has odd order and $(G_1, \alpha^{G_1})$ acts as a Frobenious group; contradicting our hypothesis.
>   Thus we see that $|\alpha^C| \ge 3$ and that $C$ is not regular on $\alpha^C$. [...] $\square$

There are some points I do not understand about this part of the proof.

1) If $|\alpha^C| \le 2$, then $C = \langle x \rangle \times U$ and thus the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic.

As $x \in C$ I see that $\alpha^C = \{\alpha\}$ is not possible, and also we must have $\alpha^C = \{\alpha, \beta\}$, and so that $C \le N_G(U)$. Also as $U^x = U$ we have $\langle U, x \rangle = U \cdot \langle x \rangle$. But why $C = \langle x \rangle \times U$? I can see that $C \le U\cdot \langle x \rangle$, as if $y \in C$ and $\alpha^y = \alpha$ then of course $y \in U$, and if $\alpha^y = \beta$ then by $\alpha^x = \beta$ we have $\beta^{xy} = \beta$, i.e. $xy \in U$, hence $y \in Ux^{-1} = Ux$. Also $C_{\alpha} \le U$. But this is all I see, but why is $U \le N_G(\langle x \rangle)$, i.e. $xu = ux$ for all $u \in U$, and why do we have $C = \langle x \rangle \times U$?

2) $(G_1, \alpha^{G_1})$ acts as a Frobenious group.

I see that $G_1$ in its action fulfills the requirement put on $G$, i.e. at most two fixed points and so, but why each element has at most one fixed point and the action is nonregular?

3) We see that $|\alpha^C| \ge 3$ and that $C$ is not regular on $\alpha^C$.

Why is $C$ not semi-regular?

If wanted I can supply the rest of the proof. Hoping someone can explain these points too me. Thank you!

Comment: I think $C=\langle x \rangle \times U$ is a mistake. They meant to write $C=\langle x \rangle \times C_U(x)$  (they have assumed here that $C_U(x)=1$). In 2), $G_1$ has two orbits on $\Omega$ which are interchanged by $x$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in different orbits, and hence, if an element of $G_\alpha$ fixes two points then they lie in different orbits of $G_1$. So elements of $G_1$ fix at most one point of $\alpha^{G_1}$. It is nonregulat because elements of $U$ are not fixed point free. Similarly, in 3), $C$ is not semiregular because elements of $C_U(x)$ fix some points.

Comment: Yes, $C = \langle x \rangle \times C_U(x)$ makes much more sense! (btw you mean they assume $C_U(x) \ne 1$...) For 2), I do not see that $G_1$ must have two orbits, just by odd order that $|\Omega| = 2k|\Delta|$ with $k \ge 1$ for some orbit $\Delta$ of $G_1$. But I see that if $G = S\cdot G_1$ with $|S| = 2^k$ then we can choose $|Q| = 2^{k-1}$ in $S$ and put $G_1' := QG_1$, now $G_1'$ has index $2$ in $G$ and so it must have two orbits? So has $G_1$ really two orbits or it is just assumed because we can build up a bigger group as above that has two orbits?

Comment: In fact $|S|=2$ (that was how they deduced that $S$ is cyclic), so $G_1$ has index $2$.

Comment: Why that, I do not see it?

Comment: Because $C$ has twice odd order.

Comment: So this is equivalent to $|G : C|$ being odd, which is the number of conjugates of $x$ in $G$, but we do not know much about that... next try $|G : G_{\alpha}||G_{\alpha} : C_{\alpha}| = |G : C||C : C_{\alpha}|$ where we know that $|G : G_{\alpha}| = |\Omega|$ is even and $|C : C_{\alpha}| = 2$, I know that $|\Omega|$ is even, but I do not know that it is not divisble by $4$, so that does not give it, what piece of information am I missing so that $|G : C|$ is forced to be odd?